# Webscraping with Python Selenium: Unable to find element and scroll, getting 'cannot focus element' error

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm scraping VividSeats website for ticket information.

url = 'https://www.vividseats.com/nhl-hockey/los-angeles-kings-tickets/kings-vs-canucks-2-14-2751065.html'

I'm using Selenium and Python. 
I'm able to go to the page using Chrome Webdriver and then click on the pop up that comes up. I tried scraping the ticket information on the left side under

```
<ul class='ticket-rows'>
```

by using `driver.find_elements_by_class_name.`

However, it's only scraping the top half of the list. Once the frame has been scrolled down, more tickets come up. Apparently just scraping didn't get those bottom half of tickets.

I tried to grab the class of the tickets and then using

```
import Keys
send_keys(Keys.END)
```

on the element to scroll to the end of the frame, and then to scrape the tickets. But I keep getting

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

errors.

I looked for the frame but there's no iframe for me to switch into. It's an inline frame that's within the page and I'm unable to switch into this to scroll to the bottom of the page.

What do I need to do to be able to scroll to the bottom of this frame so that I can scrape the tickets? I'm not asking for how to scrape, but just to know how I can get this to scroll to the end

Thanks

EDIT: Included codes I've tried as requested by @ DebanjanB

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

1)

```
scroll = driver.find_element_by_class_name('value-score')
scroll.click()
scroll.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

2)

```
scroll = driver.find_element_by_class_name('row-container')
scroll.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

3)

```
scroll = driver.find_element_by_class_name('row')
scroll.send_keys(Keys.END)
```

They all ended up returning error

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

Comment: *Maybe* this will work, I can't be sure without checking all the scrapper, but once I had a similar problem with a government site I scraped, the solution was to click anywhere else where you did **not** affect anything on the site. After that it might be possible to keep going

Comment: @uclaastro Update the question with your code trials

Comment: @Jose I tried clicking on part of that frame but it wasn't working (#1 of the update edit). Anywhere else in that frame will be clicking on the seat and takes you to purchase

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape whole list then you need to do the scroll down otherwise the elements will not be visible.

So try the below code which will scroll down first until there are no elements left and then retrieves info and prints for you.

```
// Some driver initialization code
driver.get("https://www.vividseats.com/nhl-hockey/los-angeles-kings-tickets/kings-vs-canucks-2-14-2751065.html");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='SKIP']")).click();
String xPath = "//ul[@class='ticket-rows']/article";
// Getting initial visible rows
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
while(true) {
    // Scrolling down to the last row so that remaining rows get visible
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", rows.get(rows.size()-1));
    // Getting latest loaded visible rows count
    List<WebElement> tempRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
    //  System.out.println(rows.size()+" <<<===>>> "+tempRows.size());
    // If the latest rows count is greater than the previous rows count then we need to do the scroll down again otherwise break the loop
    if(tempRows.size() > rows.size()) {
        rows = tempRows;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
// Printing the name and the price, you can change it to your convenience
List<WebElement> data = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"//strong"));
for(WebElement element : data) {
    System.out.println(element.getText().trim());
}
```

Below is the end to end code in Python :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.vividseats.com/nhl-hockey/los-angeles-kings-tickets/kings-vs-canucks-2-14-2751065.html')

popUp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='SKIP']");
popUp.click()

xPath = "//ul[@class='ticket-rows']/article";
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)
while True:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", rows[-1])
    tmpRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath)
    if len(tmpRows) > len(rows) :
        rows = tmpRows
    else:
        break
    
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xPath+"//strong"):
    print(element.text)

print("Done...")
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Do you think there's a way this can be done without using Javascript and just working through selenium?

Comment: Yes, may be you can use Selenium Actions to do that, Check out [this](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html)

Comment: I've tried using Selenium Action and Keys but both give me the same error of  : WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: @uclaastro, try my answer which I have tested and posted which is working fine

Comment: I'm using python on jupyter notebook so I don't think I am able to use python and JS at the same time, considering this is only part of the full python code